# Calendar inside UpdatePanel not working as Trigger with Master page

Tags: asp.net, triggers, calendar, updatepanel, master-pages

I got 2 test pages: one with `Master` page and second empty.

The empty one looks like this:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManager" runat="server" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="calendarUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Calendar ID="calendar" runat="server" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="timetableUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="placeHolder" runat="server" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Calendar" EventName="SelectionChanged" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

When user selects `Date` from `Calendar` (first `UpdatePanel`), I'm showing `Date` related information insite placeHolder (second `UpdatePanel`). This works on both pages.

The one with `Master` page has same `Content`. If I press '>' or '<' (next or prev month) on `Calendar` in empty page, `Calendar` gets updated and I see next/previous month. The same function on page with `Master` page does not work (if I press on next or prev month I still see same month).

Any ideas where the issue is?

Comment: sorry but i'm not able to understand what you want to do? Also if these two update panels are there why are you calling the Calender of panel "calendarUpdatePanel" into "timetableUpdatePanel". This will never work for you.

Comment: Updated. I'm trying to show `Date` related information inside second `UpdatePanel`

Answer (score 0):

You should lay the Calendar UpdatePanel to the ContentTemplate of the Controller/DisplayUnit's UpdatePanel.

So that the Calendar can interactive with the Controller/DisplayUnit.

For exmaple. the controller button can toggle the CalendarUpdatePanel.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanelControlDateEnd" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="True" RenderMode="Inline">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ImageButtonDateEnd" EventName="Click" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="CalendarDateEnd" EventName="SelectionChanged" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <span style="display:inline-block;">
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanelCalendarDateEnd" 
            UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="True" Visible="False">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Calendar ID="CalendarDateEnd" runat="server" OnSelectionChanged="CalendarDateEnd_SelectionChanged"
                Style="position:absolute;margin:5px;" BackColor="White" BorderColor="Black" DayNameFormat="Shortest"
                Font-Names="Times New Roman" Font-Size="10pt" ForeColor="Black" Height="220px"
                NextPrevFormat="FullMonth" TitleFormat="Month" Width="400px">
                    <DayHeaderStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="7pt" ForeColor="#333333"
                    Height="10pt" />
                    <DayStyle Width="14%" />
                    <NextPrevStyle Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="White" />
                    <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#999999" />
                    <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#CC3333" ForeColor="White" />
                    <SelectorStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt"
                    ForeColor="#333333" Width="1%" />
                    <TitleStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="13pt" ForeColor="White"
                    Height="14pt" />
                    <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
                </asp:Calendar>
            </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </span> 
        <span style="white-space:nowrap">
           <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxDateEnd" runat="server" Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
           <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButtonDateEnd" runat="server" OnClientClick=""
           CausesValidation="False" onclick="ImageButtonDateEnd_Click" ImageUrl="~/Resources/Images/pic_drop_down_image_button.png"
           style="left:-23px;top:0px;vertical-align:middle;position:relative;height:18px;" />
        </span>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Codes above, which were implied inside a page with Master page, were passed the testing on IE7,IE8,IE9(developing mode of IE 11),Firefox 32.(But the UpdatePanel its self sames has some js bug on IE 10/11.) So for IE 10/11, you'd better modify these codes, to avoid to use the UpdatePanel.

For example:

```
<span>
    <span style="display:inline-block;">
        <asp:Calendar ID="CalendarStart" runat="server" 
        onselectionchanged="CalendarDateStart_SelectionChanged" Visible="False" 
        style="position:absolute;margin:5px;" 
            BackColor="White" BorderColor="Black" 
            DayNameFormat="Shortest" Font-Names="Times New Roman" Font-Size="10pt" 
            ForeColor="Black" Height="220px" NextPrevFormat="FullMonth" TitleFormat="Month" 
            Width="400px">
            <DayHeaderStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="7pt" 
                ForeColor="#333333" Height="10pt" />
            <DayStyle Width="14%" />
            <NextPrevStyle Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="White" />
            <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#999999" />
            <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#CC3333" ForeColor="White" />
            <SelectorStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Verdana" 
                Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#333333" Width="1%" />
            <TitleStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="13pt" 
                ForeColor="White" Height="14pt" />
            <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
        </asp:Calendar>
    </span>
    <span style="white-space:nowrap">
      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxDateStart" runat="server" Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
      <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButtonDateStart" runat="server" OnClientClick=""
      CausesValidation="False" onclick="ImageButtonDataStart_Click" ImageUrl="~/Resources/Images/pic_drop_down_image_button.png"
      style="left:-23px;top:0px;vertical-align:middle;position:relative;height:18px;" />
    </span>
</span>
```

Have fun.

Comment: **[ATTENTION]** I just found the reason why updatepanel didn't pass the testing  on IE 11. We should not use `asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger` in the `triggers`. But choose the `asp:PostBackTrigger` instead.

Comment: Putting one UpdatePanel inside another is not an option, because one is at the beggining of the Page, and second is at the end. I would need to put entier Page inside an UpdatePanel, which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: By my understanding, you want to put an update-panel at the beginning of a page, and another to the end of the page. And you want to do the same thing on both page with and without master template page. So how about use CSS style to control them, and still keep one update-panel to another. That mean on logical one contain another, but on visualization, they are separate.

Comment: Nope. I just want to have `UpdatePanel` in my `Content` `Page`. The problem is, that having `Master` `Page` around somehow brokes the way `Calendar` is working.

Comment: I'm coding in a content page with the default master page created by the virtual studio.And I met the problem too in the very beginning. When click the month link, calendar won't change, but the page will reload, which same like a redraw. With debugging I found every time I click the next month link, there will be a post back.and cause the calendar redraw to the default status. So I choose to use the "IsPostBack", and later, I found the update panel is a good choice. I guest you may debug to see how the program  acting.